# jquery - show hidden image when insert text into input

Tags: jquery, input, show

i have a simple input field

```
<input id="pass" name="pass" value="" size="12" type="password" />
```

and a hidden image on the same page

```
<img src="./magnifier.png" id="show" alt="" style="display:none;"/>
```

is it possible to show the image (id="show") when i insert text into the input (id="pass")?

empty input = no image, text inside input = image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
$('#pass').keyup(function(){
    var hasValue = this.value.length > 0;
    $('#show')[hasValue ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s66cM/).

Or without the (perhaps overly-complex) reliance on a ternary operator:

```
$('#pass').keyup(function(){
    var hasValue = this.value.length > 0;
    $('#show').toggle(hasValue);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s66cM/1/).

In order to show the picture on page-load (assuming that `#pass` has a value):

```
$('#show').toggle($('#pass').val().length > 0);

$('#pass').keyup(function(){
    var hasValue = this.value.length > 0;
    $('#show').toggle(hasValue);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s66cM/2/).

References:

- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: hi david thomas.. your code works perfect! but i have a small question.. when i submit my form and other fields not filed with text then the php script is stopping the POST. the site does a refresh to fill out the missing fields. when i have a value inside the #pass and the site is refreshing i don't see the image. is there a way to fix that? i used your 2nd codesnippet

Comment: What happens after you submit your form becomes a [tag:php] question, after the page reloads you want to ensure the image is shown if there's a value in the `#pass` field?

Comment: yes right! i want to see the image when a value in #pass on refresh :D right now it is hiding on refresh

Comment: My pleasure; I'm glad to have been of help and thank you for the accept! =)

Comment: it's me again :( i didn't see that i have on my other pages (where i don't have these input's) an error in the error-console [Error: TypeError: $("#pass").val() is undefined]

Comment: And have you included jQuery on those pages? Do you have the relevant element(s) on those pages? The answer posted works, as requested, for other problems you either need to debug your application/site, or ask another question specific to those problems.

Comment: i got it.. just added $('#show').toggle($('#pass').val().length > 0); direct into the html file.. before it was in my js file :D thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#pass').keypress(function(){
        if($(this).val()!='')
        $('#show').show() //or may be with an effect
            else
        $('#show').hide()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pass').keyup(function () {
        var value=$('#pass').val();
        if (value != "") {
            $("#show").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $("#show").css("display", "none");
        }

    });
```

please correct it if I am wrong.